# HTML Encoding Strings - ASP.NET Web Forms VS Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewengine, html-encode

I'm not quite sure how this works yet... trying to find documentation.

In my existing app I've got two different ways of rendering strings in my View

```
<%: model.something %>
<!-- or -->
<%= model.something %>
```

The first one is html encoded, and the second one is not.

Is there something similarly short in Razor?  All I can find is this, which is the encoded version.

```csharp
@model.something
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I guess the best approach would be to use the Raw extension-method: `@Html.Raw(Model.Something)`

Comment: I received an email from Marcind stating that we should in fact be using this.

Answer (score 15):

`@Model.Something` automatically HTML encodes. If you want to avoid HTML encoding (and you want this only if you are absolutely sure what you are doing) you could use `@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.Something)` (basically everything that implements [IHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) won't be encoded). Phil Haack [blogged](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/03/razor-view-syntax.aspx) about the Razor view engine syntax.

Comment: cool thanks.  Do you know if they're working on a shorter syntax for sending a string unencoded? something like `@=Model.Something` would be nice.  Not saying that is the right way, just some idea.

Comment: We are looking at something like that for v2 of Razor.

Comment: I'll be ecstatic when this comes to fruition. In fact, it would be nice to be able to set this in a buddy class as well so that it's set and forget. `<DisableHtmlEncode()>` for the `@Html.EditorFor()`

Comment: +1 for the `IHtmlString` but not the answer. I prefer @Magnus answer which is `@Html.Raw(Model.Something)`

Comment: I just received an email from Marcind stating that we should in fact be using `@Html.Raw()`