# Replace line break characters with <br /> in ASP.NET MVC Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a textarea control that accepts input. I am trying to later render that text to a view by simply using:

> @Model.CommentText

This is properly encoding any values.  However, I want to replace the line break characters with `<br />` and I can't find a way to make sure that the new br tags don't get encoded. I have tried using HtmlString but haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: I presume linebreaks are stored as `\n` in the database and you want to convert to a `<br />`?

Comment: Yes - just trying to replace \n with <br /> in the view.

Answer (score 787, accepted):

Use the [CSS white-space property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) instead of opening yourself up to XSS vulnerabilities!

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">@Model.CommentText</span>
```

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html has a good explanation of `pre-line` (I was only aware of `nowrap` and `pre`).

Comment: actually `white-space: pre-wrap;` is better since `pre-line` will mess with your text by grouping white spaces into one space.

Comment: @ChtiwiMalek: I certainly agree that you usually want to preserve all white space, but the original question asked about converting linebreaks into `<br />`s

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in almost any email client (including Office 2013).

Comment: One caveat with this approach is that due to browser bugs the new lines will be lost on copy-paste. See 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1174452 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=317365

Answer (score 122):

Try the following:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.CommentText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

### Update:

According to `marcind's` comment on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173483/html-encoding-strings-aspx-vs-razor-view-engines/4173500#4173500), the ASP.NET MVC team is looking to implement something similar to the `<%:` and `<%=` for the Razor view engine.

### Update 2:

We can turn any question about HTML encoding into a discussion on harmful user inputs, but enough of that already exists.

Anyway, take care of potential harmful user input.

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.Encode(Model.CommentText).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

### Update 3 (Asp.Net MVC 3):

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.CommentText).Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

Comment: Oh my GOD, no. What if I decide to comment about some `<script>`.

Comment: Thanks - that worked. Was very close but must have been doing the replace too soon or too late.  I ended up using this: 

@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.Encode(Model.CommentText).Replace("\n", "<br />"))             because Environment.NewLine wasn't working right.

Comment: @thekaido - I recommend that you do all the replacing and encoding in the controller and passing a `IHtmlString` to the view or creating a custom `HtmlHelper` that does all this for you. Seeing this line of code in a view can be painful.

Comment: Environment.NewLine doesn't really apply to form posts since browsers usually return just `\n` instead of `\r\n`

Comment: For the released version of MVC 3, the suggestion appears to be @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.CommentText).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")), instead of using MvcHtmlString. At least for display.

Comment: Environment.NewLine represent "\r\n". If my user entered data using linux or mac, linebreaks are just "\n" or "\r". Isn't there a method somewhere that takes this into account?

Comment: Even with MVC3 this solution looks quite ugly. It's rather long, you have to look twice to be sure everything gets encoded right and you have problems with different kinds of newlines. The CSS-based solution below is much better!

Comment: @SandRock: "Some\r\n string\nand a newline ".Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "<br />") note that you can safely omit Replace("\r", "")

Comment: @Quandary a bit too brute-force to me. Prefer checking the kind of linebreak before replacing: https://gist.github.com/3653055

Answer (score 13):

Split on newlines (environment agnostic) and print regularly -- no need to worry about encoding or xss:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) 
{
    var lines = text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        <p>@line</p>
    }
}
```

*(remove empty entries is optional)*

Answer (score 11):

Omar's third solution as an HTML Helper would be:

```
public static IHtmlString FormatNewLines(this HtmlHelper helper, string input)
{
    return helper.Raw(helper.Encode(input).Replace("\n", "<br />"));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Applying the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to Omar's solution, here's an HTML Helper extension:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html {
    public static class MyHtmlHelpers {
        public static MvcHtmlString EncodedReplace(this HtmlHelper helper, string input, string pattern, string replacement) {
            return new MvcHtmlString(Regex.Replace(helper.Encode(input), pattern, replacement));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (with improved regex):

```
@Html.EncodedReplace(Model.CommentText, "[\n\r]+", "<br />")
```

This also has the added benefit of putting less onus on the Razor View developer to ensure security from XSS vulnerabilities.

---

My concern with Jacob's solution is that rendering the line breaks with CSS breaks the [HTML semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML).

Answer (score 4):

I needed to break some text into paragraphs ("p" tags), so I created a simple helper using some of the recommendations in previous answers (thank you guys).

```
public static MvcHtmlString ToParagraphs(this HtmlHelper html, string value) 
    { 
        value = html.Encode(value).Replace("\r", String.Empty);
        var arr = value.Split('\n').Where(a => a.Trim() != string.Empty);
        var htmlStr = "<p>" + String.Join("</p><p>", arr) + "</p>";
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlStr);
    }
```

Usage:

```
@Html.ToParagraphs(Model.Comments)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method as it doesn't require manually emitting markup. I use this because I'm rendering Razor Pages to strings and sending them out via email, which is an environment where the white-space styling won't always work.

```
public static IHtmlContent RenderNewlines<TModel>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> html, string content)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content) || html is null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    TagBuilder brTag = new TagBuilder("br");
    IHtmlContent br = brTag.RenderSelfClosingTag();
    HtmlContentBuilder htmlContent = new HtmlContentBuilder();

    // JAS: On the off chance a browser is using LF instead of CRLF we strip out CR before splitting on LF.
    string lfContent = content.Replace("\r", string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    string[] lines = lfContent.Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        _ = htmlContent.Append(line);
        _ = htmlContent.AppendHtml(br);
    }

    return htmlContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply put this inside your div where that text is and it will work.

```
<p>@Html.Raw(notam.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br>").Replace("\n", "<br>"))</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?