# Replace \n with <br />

Tags: python, string, replace, newline

I'm parsing text from a file with Python. I have to replace all newlines with `<br />`. I tried this code:

```
thatLine.replace('\n', '<br />')
print thatLine
```

But I still see the text with newline after it. Why?

Comment: Consider a CSS only solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7602751/74449 to reduce potential for XSS

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Just for kicks, you could also do

```
mytext = "<br />".join(mytext.split("\n"))
```

to replace all newlines in a string with `<br />`.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this, but please accept @Falmarri's answer instead. It's much more Pythonic. This here is more of a funny, backwards way of doing it. Not really recommended...

Comment: Don't know about @Falmarri's answer being "more Pythonic", but it's more efficient and probably faster.

Comment: @martineau: I meant this in the sense of "There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it.". And I'm pretty sure that mine isn't the one.

Comment: This was the only method that worked for my example and I tried a few! Thanks!

Answer (score 189):

`thatLine = thatLine.replace('\n', '<br />')`

str.replace() returns a copy of the string, it doesn't modify the string you pass in.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 24):

For some reason using python3 I had to escape the "\"-sign

```
somestring.replace('\\n', '')
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Would give +2. 5 stars!

Comment: If you use double quotes around the \n, you would not have to escape it.

Comment: You might still need to escape it even if using double quotes

Answer (score 14):

To handle many newline delimiters, including character combinations like `\r\n`, use [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) (see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43641376/3780389)) use the following:

```
'<br />'.join(thatLine.splitlines())
```

Answer (score 8):

```
thatLine = thatLine.replace('\n', '<br />')
```

Strings in Python are immutable.
You might need to recreate it with the assignment operator.

Answer (score 4):

You could also have problems if the string has `<`, `>` or `&` chars in it, etc. Pass it to `cgi.escape()` to deal with those.

http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html?highlight=cgi#cgi.escape

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is When you denote `'\n'` in the `replace()` call , `'\n'` is treated as a `String length=4`  made out of `' \ n '`
To get rid of this, use ascii notation. http://www.asciitable.com/

example:

```
newLine = chr(10)
thatLine=thatLine.replace(newLine , '<br />')
```

`print(thatLine) #python3`

`print thatLine #python2` .

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I tried the suggested answers and unfortunately simply replacing line breaks with `<br />` didn't do what I needed it to. It simply rendered them literally as text.

One solution would have been to disable autoescape like this: `{% autoescape false %}{{ mystring }}{% endautoescape %}` and this works fine but this is no good if you have user-provided content. So this was also not a solution for me.

So this is what I used:

In Python:

```
newvar = mystring.split('\n')
```

And then, passing `newvar` into my Jinja template:

```
{% for line in newvar %}
    <br />{{ line }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If in case you are trying to replace the /n of a string to `</br>`,
i am speculating that you want to parse line break in HTML view.

```
word-break: break-all,
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Adding these to styles to parent `div/container` of the text will solve your problem without any string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do this using replace, and the 
 is not working for you (as was the case for me), you can use the following:

```
text_to_split = r'Hello\n\n I am a test.'
split_text = text_to_split.replace('\\n', '\n')
```

You first escape the \ in the sample text, and then by not escaping in the replacement text, it will generate a new line.