# Python script that executes SQL: Preserve line breaks in SQL text when creating a view

Tags: python, sql, oracle, line-breaks, text-formatting

I have a [Python script](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/executing-sql-using-an-arcsde-connection.htm) that I run in PyScripter (Windows) that I use to execute SQL on an Oracle database. The SQL creates a view.

```
import sys
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = sys.path[0]
egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(r"Database Connections\Connection1.sde")
sql_statement = """

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ROAD_VW AS
SELECT
    NAME
    ,FROM_
    ,TO_
FROM
    USER1.ROAD

"""
egdb_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql_statement)
print "Complete."
```

The script successfully creates a view in the database.

The problem is that the line breaks in the database view definition only seem to work (be visible) in certain programs, not others. If I access the view definition (in say - MS Access or ArcGIS Desktop), copy it, then paste it, this happens:

Line breaks are visible in:

```
SELECT
    NAME
    ,FROM_
    ,TO_
FROM
    USER1.ROAD
```

1. Stack Overflow
2. Microsoft Word
3. PyScripter

---

Line breaks are **not** visible in:

```
SELECT        NAME        ,FROM_        ,TO_    FROM        USER1.ROAD
```

4. Notepad
5. MS Access >> SQL editor
6. ArcGIS Desktop >> Create View

Can I format the SQL text so that, when it's executed to create a view, the view definition's line breaks are preserved (when the SQL definition text is used in other programs)?

Comment: maybe you can have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1761064/1013142) and use that for new lines in your code. That is a suggestion and not a tested answer, MS Access or ArcGIS applications might be displaying them the way they want.

Comment: Is the Python running on Linux, i.e. are the line breaks in the Python just a line feed LF and Oracle requires a carriage return as well (CRLF).

Comment: @Ben I've updated the question: `I have a Python script that I run in PyScripter (Windows) that I use to execute SQL on an Oracle database.` The python is running on Windows. I don't have any details about the Oracle Server, but my uneducated guess is that it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Ben Thanks, I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by @Sudipta Mondal, I need to convert `\n` to `\r\n`:

`sql_statement = sql_statement.replace('\n', '\r\n')`

---

Related resources:

[Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r/1761064#1761064)

[Replace \n with {something else}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4369166/5576771)