# Split a string on new lines and format every line different, depending on the line number

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to split a string on new lines and format every line different, depending on the line number and on the beginning of that line.

I found an example wich could be nice for my task([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220381/replace-line-break-characters-with-br-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view)):

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model[i].Services[j].ServiceDescription).Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

But this needs still some addition like:

- first line: big caption, formating it.(`<h1> text from that model </h1>`)
- second line: middle Caption, formating it.(`<h4> text from that model </h4>`)
- third line: normal text, without formating
- bigger than third line:if "Model[i].Services[j].ServiceDescription" contains "-" than print `<ul><li>Model[i].Services[j].ServiceDescription</li><ul>` for every new "-" add it to it like:
  `<ul>
  <li>Model[i].Services[j].ServiceDescription first "-"text </li><li>Model[i].Services[j].ServiceDescription second "-"text </li>
  <ul>`

And I thought I can go like that:

```
<h1>@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model[i].Services[j].ServiceDescription).Replace("\n", "<br />"))</h1>
```

But this would format the entire text with `<h1>` caption, so I need kind of a `for`-loop and `if` to iterate throug the string, may be like this:

[no JavaScript, but c# ( I put this into fiddler,because I couldn't format it here)](http://jsfiddle.net/K85K7/1/)

An example input looks like:

> "First line\r\nSecond line\r\nThird line\r\n-First Li_Element\r\n-Second Li_Element\r\nNormal text again."

By the way I found something like this [split up a string on new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net).

How can I realize it, I don't know how to put all the single parts together to a working code ?

**UPDATE:**
I did something like that:

```
@BWHtml.ToParagraphs(Model[i].Services[j].ServiceDescription)
```

I did something like that:

[click](http://jsfiddle.net/K85K7/2/)

**UPDATE(FINAL):**
 [final](http://jsfiddle.net/K85K7/3/)

Do you see any danger in this code regarding security issues or any suggestions in improving performance ?

Comment: updated, closer to the solution

Comment: updated again. Do you see any danger in this code regarding security issues( XSS vulnerabilities .. )  or any suggestions in improving performance ? http://jsfiddle.net/K85K7/3/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Custom HTML Helper is the way to go for you, creating method `CustomHtmlHelper.FormatParagraphs`, splitting the given strings by lines, modify it to your needs and return a `MvcHtmlString`.

For additional information about [**Creating Custom HTML Helpers**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).