# line break is not working in cshtml view page when I use br tag

Tags: razor

I have a cshtml that renders a model. One of the property has "\r\n" I want to use as a line break. so what I do is call

```
@Model.Message.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")
```

But the razor engine renders as <br />
Any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace line break characters with <br /> in ASP.NET MVC Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220381/replace-line-break-characters-with-br-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view)

Answer (score 0):

Just found the following solution:

```
 @(new HtmlString(Model.Message.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")))
```

It works perfectly!