# How to replace '\n' in string with '<br>' in Flask app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I've been trying to modify a string before passing it to my HTML page in Flask (replacing occurrences of '\n' with '<br>'), but the typical methods I use aren't working for some reason.

```py
finalstring = textstring.replace('\n', '<br>')
return render_template('my-form-result.html', emailresponse = finalstring)
```

This should work, but for some reason, nothing is replaced. How can I get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: I've never worked with Flask, but it looks like Flasks templating engine escapes HTML Structures (which is a good thing). For your use-case, you have to figure out how to give flask explicit raw-html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)

Comment: Can you show us how "textstring" looks like?

Comment: @codeflush.dev It does escape HTML, unless told to do otherwise, which is not a great idea.

Comment: What do you mean, _"nothing is replaced"_? That cannot be. Try `print(repr(finalstring))` and see if it has any `\n` in it. Explain exactly what happens incorrectly.

Comment: That's why I'm so confused. It should be working. Just tried print(repr(finalstring)) and it just printed an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to replace `\n` in HTML is [using CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602751/281048).

Your `replace()` is alright. Debug your code and make sure there is `\n` before `replace()`.

To be able to view linebreaks in HTML you should use `safe` filter in the template. But beware that you become open to XSS attacks. To get round this problem you should escape the string before replacing the `\n` character. This is the code:

```py
from flask import escape

...
...
    safe_html = str(escape(text)).replace('\n', '<br/>')
    return render_template('[HTML file].html', safe_html=safe_html)

---------
#in the template:
   <span> {{ safe_html | safe }} </span>
```

If you don't use the `str()` call before replace, then the `<br/>` will be scaped too. Because the return value from `escape()` is not `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I never worked with Flask, I just looked it up and hope it does what you want to do.

So somewhere in your template `my-form-result.html` you should find a line containing:

```
{{ emailresponse }}
```

You can replace this with:

```
{% for line in emailresponse.split('\n') %}
{{ line }}
<br />
{% endfor %}
```

To add an `br` after every newline

Answer (score 0):

Your `replace()` code is correct.  Make sure you escape the HTML in the template:

```
{{ emailresponse|safe }}
```

To diagnose, try this:

```
finalstring = textstring.replace('\n', '<br>')
print(finalstring)
return render_template('my-form-result.html', emailresponse = finalstring)
```

Also, show us the source code from the web page, to see what is actually rendering in the template

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, I have tried each of the recommended solutions, and nothing has worked. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Show us the rendering of this from View Source Code from your browser.